# pythonで辞書を出力した時のカッコを消したい。

Tags: python

初心者です。

```
d = {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}
dic = list(d.keys())
print(dic)
```

これを出力すると

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

となるのですが、[]と ' そして , を消したものを変数化したいです。

ちなみに、

```
print(*dic)
```

とやってみた際、使用しているモジュール(discord.py)の影響でできませんでした。
つまり、

```
print(dic_after)
```

のみで

```
a b c
```

の出力がほしいということです。
わかりずらいかもですがご了承願います。

Comment: "とやってみた際、使用しているモジュール(discord.py)の影響でできませんでした。" の部分が不明でした。"できませんでした"だと伝わりません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

例えば `' '.join(dic)` は如何でしょう？
以下のように出来るでしょう。

```
d = {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}
dic = list(d.keys())
print(dic)
dic_after = ' '.join(dic)
print(dic_after)
```